# Implementing Partial Trace in IBMs quantum computer

Tags: programming, decoherence, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement the partial trace operation on IBMs quantum computer. I am simulating the depolarising channel with the following code

```
#aim here is to build the decoherence channel
p=0.1;
z=0.5+0.5*math.sqrt(1-p);
desiredvec=[
    math.sqrt(1-z),
    math.sqrt(z)]
circuit2 = QuantumCircuit(4,3);
circuit2.initialize(desiredvec,0)
circuit2.initialize(desiredvec,1)
circuit2.initialize(desiredvec,2)
circuit2.cx(0,3)
circuit2.h(3)
circuit2.s(3)
circuit2.cx(1,3)
circuit2.h(3)
circuit2.s(3)
circuit2.cx(2,3)
circuit2.h(3)
circuit2.s(3)
circuit2.draw()
```

I would now like to trace out all but qubit 3 as it is the only qubit I am interested in. I can get around this by just ignoring the other qubits but I would rather not do this. Is there any easy way to trace out unwanted qubits?

Or equivalently is there a way to initalise the qubit in a mixed state so that the extra ancillary qubits aren't needed in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qiskit.quantum_info` has a [partial_trace](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.partial_trace.html) method you can use for this.

It takes as input either a `Statevector` or a `DensityMatrix` object. Both these classes implement the `from_instruction` routine that you can use with the `QuantumCircuit` object you already have. You would have to do something along the lines of:

```
circuit2 = QuantumCircuit(4,3)

...
# your operations
...

statevec = Statevector.from_instruction(circuit2)
trace = partial_trace(statevec, 3)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

On a quantum computer, there is *no point* in implementing a partial trace.  Just ignore the qubits which you want to trace.

Comment: What if the final state is correlated?

Comment: @Pedro On a quantum computer, there is no point in implementing a partial trace. Just ignore the qubits which you want to trace. This implements the partial trace - regardless of whether the qubits are correlated or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering cause it seems to be relevant, e.g., in  [arXiv:1204.6308](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6308), page 3, they explicitly say "In order to simulate tracing over the other qubit, a set of experiments is run with additional rotations to measure the final populations p00, p01, p10, p11".